# Textarea cursor not starting from beginning

Tags: html

I have a `<textarea>` in HTML. When I put cursor in it, it's not starting from the beginning, but is blinking in middle.

#### HTML

```
<TD width="21%">
    <textarea class="txtarea" style="height:30px;" rows="3" name="Text" Id="Text" value=""> </textarea>
</TD>
```

#### CSS

```
.txtarea{
    border-right: #646464 ;
    border-top: #646464;
    border-left: #646464;
    border-bottom: #646464;
    width:100%;
    background: #ffffcc;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. You probably have text-align: center; set somewhere else in your css that's affecting this. What does Firebug tell you?

Comment: also remove whitespace between <textarea></textarea> tags

Comment: @Tom:Thanks.There were spaces between tags.Working.

Comment: Also, there is no need to write css in ALL CAPS

Answer (score 199, accepted):

```
<textarea class="txtarea" style="height:30px;" rows="3" name="Text" Id="Text" value=""> </textarea>
```

What you have is a space between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I was having the same issue. I had </textarea> on a new line, thus giving me the whitespace. This was driving me insane for an hour! +1 for @Tom! :)

Answer (score 3):

Textarea's opening and closing tag must be in same line because Whatever in between textarea tag it will considered as "value" of textarea.
Now for below code placeholder will also shown as expected.

```
<textarea
  placeholder="Enter text here" 
  class="txtarea"
  style="height:30px;"
  rows="3"
  name="Text"
  id="text"
></textarea>
```